# Zend Framework 2 Tools

Tags: zend-framework2

I've being looking around for Zend\Tool which appears in version 1 but not in version 2. I did find another SO post where it was mentioned that they've not been added yet but that was over 6 months old.

Does anyone have an update on when they will be added or can point me in the direction of similar utilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZFTool is now available for Zend Framework 2: https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as Zend Tool at the moment. They are still working on it but when it will be released, no one can tell yet. However there are two great Git-Repositories out there, that pretty much cover crucial aspects of Zend Tool - creating a bare application and new modules

- [zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication)
- [zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule)

Additionally someone posted a shell script to create a new skeleton module on [my Blog](http://samminds.com), you can find the script right there. However i take no responsibility for that script, as i don't use it myself. ZF2 Modules are so simple and the SkeletonModule is all i need:

- [zf2crmod.sh](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/67895339/zf2crmod.sh)

Comment: this is now out of date :)